# Extracting 7z Console SFX (.exe) files using Python without using a subprocess?

Tags: python, 7zip, zip, lzma

I am using python 3.4

I have a crawler that is extracting 7z Console SFX files and I wish to extract them programmatically.

Currently I have only been able to do so with a subprocess call:

```
import subprocess
seven_zip = r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
tempfile = r"temp.exe" # SFX Archive
subprocess.call(seven_zip + ' x ' + tempfile + ' -aoa')
```

This is problematic because users of this script may not have 7zip installed, or may have it installed in a different directory.  Further, running a subprocess doesn't give me direct access to the extracted items like running a normal zFile extraction would.  I can workaround this by extracting to a temporary directory then parsing the files in said directory, but that is cumbersome.

I am thinking there's got to be a way of extracting the 7z Console SFX files with Python (maybe something with [pylzma](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma)?), but I can't seem to find any questions on the subject here.

**Update:** I've still had limited success using py7zlib. Again I note that this is intended for extracting SFX (executable) archives, and not a .7z archive.  Perhaps there is an application for py7zlib for such files, but I'm unable to find any examples.

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/py7zlib.py

Comment: See accepted answer to question [_How to read from a text file compressed with 7z in Python_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104460/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-compressed-with-7z-in-python) which shows how to use the `py7zlib` module to extract 7z files.

Comment: I've still had limited success, specifically as related to extracting 7z SFX files (they have a .exe extension, not a typical .7z one).  Am I missing the obvious here? py7zlib doesn't seem to work in this case.