# Python: How can I read a line from a compressed 7z file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.4, 7zip

I have a multi-GB 7z archive that contains a single `xml` file. I want to read a single line from this compressed file at a time till it's (the file's) `EOF` is reached on Python 3.4. I cannot afford to decompress it into it's full size, which is around a couple of Terabytes.

I was suggested many libraries like `pylzma` and `lzma` but they don't support 7z format.
`libarchive` does support 7z but it reads in blocks, which are not necessarily lines of text in the file, I think.

Please provide suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: If libarchive reads in block, you could use this to read until you find a `'\n'`, and yield it, creating your own lines generator. But are you sure your uncompressed file contains carriage returns?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it contains newline characters. Could you elaborate on using `yield` till the newline? I have a code for the `yield` part as you suggest from here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104460/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-compressed-with-7z-in-python

Answer (score 0):

(elaborating on the yield part) Note, I do not know this lib or what function you use to get blocks of uncompressed data. But I mean something like this:

```
def 7zreadline(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh: #automatically closes filehandler when finished
        archive = py7zlib.Archive7z(fh)
        current_line = ''
        for block in archive.getblock(): #I do not know how you get a block of uncompressed data, so I ''abstract'' the call, you get the idea...
            current_line += block
            while '\n' in current_line:
                yield current_line[:current_line.index('\n')+1] # gives all until '\n' to the caller
                current_line = current_line[current_line.index('\n')+1:] # now, initialize current_line with the rest of your block.
        yield current_line #return the end of file
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
for line in 7zreadline('myfile.zip'):
    print(line)
```

If someone who knows the library can get something correct, edits are welcome.

Comment: Thanks. Shall give it a try.

Comment: @DainDwarf you might need to do `while '\n' in block`, otherwise you'll only yield maximum one line per block (if blocksize is 1024, with pretty-printed XML, one might expect several dozens of lines per block).

Comment: That's true! maybe a block.split('\n')