# read a .7z file in memory with Python, and process each line as a stream

Tags: python, string, 7zip, in-memory, libarchive

I'm working with a huge .7z file that I need to process line by line.

First I tried `py7zr`, but it only works by first decompressing the whole file into an object. This runs out of memory.

Then `libarchive` is able to read block by block, but there's no straightforward way of splitting these binary blocks into lines.

What can I do?

Related questions I researched first:

- [How to read contents of 7z file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797851/how-to-read-contents-of-7z-file-using-python): The answers only decompress the whole file.
- [How to read from a text file compressed with 7z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104460/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-compressed-with-7z): Seeks Python 2.7 answers.
- [Python: How can I read a line from a compressed 7z file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135592/python-how-can-i-read-a-line-from-a-compressed-7z-file-in-python): Focuses on a single line, no accepted answer - only answer posted 7 years ago.

I'm looking for ways to improve the temporary solution I built myself - posted as an answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution goes through all available `get_blocks()`. If the last line doesn't end in `\n`, we keep the remaining bytes to be `yield` on the next block.

```py
import libarchive

def process(my_file):
    data = ''
    with libarchive.file_reader(my_file) as e:
        for entry in e:
            for block in entry.get_blocks():
                data += block.decode('ISO-8859-1')
                lines = data.splitlines()
                if not data.endswith('\n'):
                    data = lines.pop()
                else:
                    data = ''
                for line in lines:
                    yield ({'l': line},)
```