# Cannot install py7zlib package using Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, 7zip, py7zlib

I am trying to install py7zlib package, however I am getting below error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py7zlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for py7zlib
```

I am using Python 3.6.

I tried:

```
pip install py7zlib
```

I would like to have this package working properly.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma)?

Comment: I would like to use py7zlib package, because I cannot install pylzma as well.

Comment: Could you add a link or something to the py7zlib package you are trying to install? The only thing I can find is a file in the `pylzma` package with that name

Comment: If you are using Windows, you can download a pre-built version of `pylzma` module from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). I think it includes the `py7zlib` you want.

Comment: Thanks, @martineau. I will try this. Could you please instruct how to install pre-build version of this package? Thank you in advance.

Comment: b36: See [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: b36: [How to read from a text file compressed with 7z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104460/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-compressed-with-7z) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

pip install pylzma.

This package include py7zlib

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.