# How to read files from 7z archive with Python?

Tags: python, archive, 7zip

I have a .7z file (archive) and I am trying to find out how to read files from 7z archive? I cannot find any information how to do that. Is there any library for that purpose? I tried zipfile, lzma, however none of them works.

I will be very grateful for any advice.

Best

Comment: I was able to use [libarchive](https://pypi.org/project/libarchive/) to handle 7z.

Comment: You can use py7zr, which supports 7zip archive compression, decompression, encryption and decryption. https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr

Answer (score 1):

Look for libarchive or pylzma

https://pypi.org/project/pylzma/

Would help to know which version of Python you are using

Comment: I am using Python 3.6

Comment: Look for :https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292596/9232914

Comment: When I am trying to install this lib I am getting:
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py7zlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for py7zlib"

Comment: Installing with pip or curl ?